# Compact logic without the downward Skolem-Löwenheim property

Tags: logic, model-theory

Lindström's theorem suggests the existence of a compact logic without the downward Skolem-Löwenheim property.  My main source for this kind of matter is Barwise and Feferman's *Model-Theoretic Logics*.  Unfortunately, the book does not make it easy for me to answer this question. More seriously, many matters in this book (for instance, Ziegler's work on model theory of topological spaces) is forgotten nowadays.  Thus my question is: what are compact logics without the downward Skolem-Löwenheim property in which people are still interested in?

Comment: First-order logic with a quantifier for "There are uncountably many" is countably compact; I believe this is covered in the Barwise-Feferman book. For an example of a fully compact logic beyond first order, see section 16 of ["Remarks in abstract model theory"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007285900028) by Shelah; more generally, googling "Shelah compact logic" turns up a wealth of sources. I don't know what current interest looks like, however.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for your comment.  There does not seem to be Section 16 in the paper to which you posted a link;  could you clarify what  you meant?

Comment: Sorry, section 6.